# Angular material DatePicker different behaviour when input field by hand

Tags: angular, forms, datepicker, angular-material

I have an angular DatePicker component in my input form like this.

```
<div class="input-group">   

              <input 

              id="entryDate" 
              type="text" 
              class="form-control"  
              [mdDatepicker]="myDatepicker" 
              [(ngModel)]="position.entryDate" name="entryDate">   

              <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button 
                [mdDatepickerToggle]="myDatepicker" 
                 class="btn btn-secondary" 
                 type="button">>Go!</button>
                </span>
                <md-datepicker #myDatepicker></md-datepicker>

          </div>
```

If I select with the UI a date for example August first I get a ususal European value of dd/MM/yyyy but if I input this value by hand manually into the form I get MM/dd/yyyy on the output.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour?

Comment: what is your system date configurations?

Comment: Looks like European dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: What is `position.entryDate` value ?

Comment: Well in the case with the UI it is exitDate: Mon Jan 01 1 03:00:00 GMT+0300 and in the case if I input by hand it is 
Sun Jan 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300

Comment: Just decided to force users use the picker using the disabled tag so far

Comment: ok that also will work :) Check plunker for ref: https://plnkr.co/edit/bL9qLW7IMCzYEjd5a74l?p=preview